# SQL Get totals of each item

Tags: sql, database

Please bear with me, as I have very little SQL knowledge.

Basically, I would like to be able to generate a list of totals from a table that holds data for various locations. Within the table, each row references the location's ID and has a value:

```
ID      LocationID          Value
___    ____________        _______
 1          11               500
 2          11               400
 3          12               500
 4          12               600
 5          12               300
 6          13               400
 7          13               500
```

I would like to produce a list with each locationID and the total of all values within the "data" table.

Desired output:

```
LocationID         Total
__________         _____
    11              900
    12              1400
    13              900
```

I am sorry if I have explained it poorly... Like I said, I have very limited knowledge of SQL so I simply do not know where to start. If somebody could simply point me in the correct direction I would be very grateful.

Comment: Please consider running through a beginner SQL tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below:

```
 SELECT LocationID, sum(value) AS Total
 FROM data
 GROUP BY LocationID;
```

I am assuming `data` is your table name and `LocationID` and `value` are column names.